# Возможно ли в gitlab запретить мерж реквест, если не заполнено описание?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Требуется запретить мерж реквест, если не было заполнено описание. Возможно ли это. Если да, то в какую сторону двигаться?

Comment: Hook'и, наверное...

Answer (score 0):

Если в вебке перейдете в настройки проекта:

`Settings -> Merge requests -> Merge checks`, то нужные вам галочки там не увидите. Но там есть **"Pipelines must succeed"**. Следовательно, проверку можно сделать средствами GitLab CI, где во встроенной переменной ([GitLab CI predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)) `CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE` будет описание, которое нужно проверять при `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"`.

Пример `gitlab-ci.yml` с единственным стейджем и проверкой непустого описания merge request:

```yaml
---

stages:
  - check

mr description check:
  stage: check
  script:
    - if [ -z "$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE" ]; then echo "MR description is empty." && exit 1; fi
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
```